# Why are my gears slipping on my bike?

Tags: motorcycle

I adjusted my bars i put bigger ones but didnt change any wires. I noticed my bike not going into gear like it used to before I put the new bars. Maybe its slipping. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You're not describing what's going on very well. The statements "not going into gear" and "slipping" do not seem to go together to me. The first meaning it grinds (or "thunks" on a bike), while the second would imply there's an issue after it goes into gear. Can you please clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: @Juan Lopez are you (Probably) referring to HANDLEbars & clutch "wires"???

Answer (score 2):

Check your clutch cable slack. It's possible the cable is now stretched or routed differently, which is resulting in a change in performance.

If you have too much slack, you may not be engaging the clutch all the way when you pull the lever. This will result in hard shifting. If you have too little slack, the clutch may not be disengaging entirely, which would result in loss of power and a slipping clutch.